# Prove that if a graph of order n ≥ 6 has an Eulerian u − v trail such that deg u − deg v ≥ n − 2, then n must be even.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if a graph of order n ≥ 6 has an Eulerian u − v trail such that
deg u − deg v ≥ n − 2, then n must be even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $G$ is of order $n$, and $\deg u-\deg v\ge n-2$, you can say exactly what the degrees of $u$ and $v$ are. Then use what you know about the degrees of the endpoints of an Eulerian trail.

Comment: OK, if I understand this right, deg u = n-1 and deg v = 1, and n has to be even, because u and v both have to be odd.

Comment: @Brian: That’s right.